# UIButton responds slow to the continuous taps?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The button control in xamarin I am using has some very different issue that I haven't met before. The issue is that If I tap on the button very fast and continuously for many times it processing all the taps very slowly. It is visibly irritating that it keep on blinking even after I stopped.

Below is my code

**UI Creation Code**

```
        QRButton = new Button
        {
            Text="Title",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0064A4"),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            WidthRequest = 250.0,
            BorderRadius = 0
        };
        //add event handler
        QRButton.Clicked += QRButtonPressed;
```

**Button Action**

```
    private void QRButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("QR Generation Started");
        // Some long running process
        Console.WriteLine("QR Generation Completed");
    }
```

**The Renderer Implementation**

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(e.NewElement!=null)
        {
            Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            Control.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            Control.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Some long running process" How is this called?

Comment: It is called on main thread

Comment: Push that call to a non-UI `GCD` queue so you do not block the UI and allow multiple requests to queue up, or disable the button while your "process" is running.

Comment: @SushiHangover I actually removed all code from the button but it seems highlighting event is not happening for all taps.Have you ever experienced like this before. in xamarin?

Comment: No I have not...assuming you are talking about an `TouchUpInside` event. Also assuming you are testing on a physical device with a Release/ad-hoc build.

Comment: @SushiHangover, No I am talking about Button Class in xamarin.forms, there you can't wire up 'TouchUpInside' if i am not wrong.

Comment: If by common code you are talking about `Xamarin.Forms` code, there is some minor event propagation overhead in using a Forms' `Button` but it will not effect the native highlighting (assuming you are not changing other `Button` attributes during the event). Are you testing on a physical device with a Release/ad-hoc build?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes I am testing it in real device in debug mode.And also it looks like taps got queued up. But I don't want that to happen.Is it possible? In order  to make the app unresponsive I moved everything inside the main thread, But still the tap actions got queued up and appear to be blinking after I completed my series of taps.

Comment: Then do not allow the user to tap multiple times while you are perform the work in the background, simply disable/enable the button before/after your processing....